# GET Mapreduce Job Progress after Job finished

Tags: hive, hadoop2

[image]I'm developing a application that can collect mpreduce job progress info to analyze.The first way is parse log file.but It's ugly。Is there any method like hook or plugin can do this

Comment: What do you mean by progress info?

Comment: hi,I want to collect info like1 the pict shows

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the YARN application API to get most of the information. See this [Yarn Application API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Information_API)

Here is an excerpt from the page:

> ... All query parameters for this api will filter on all applications. However the queue query parameter will only implicitly filter on unfinished applications that are currently in the given queue.

There are other YARN APIs too, that you can utilize to achieve your goal. It is certainly better than scanning log files.

Comment: through the api,myaybe i get the final state and progress,

Comment: You can use this: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Application_API

Look at the `progress` element of the `app` object